# Add active state to 'a' tag under Bootstrap 5 nav-tabs in mvc application when using ActionLink

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-5

I have a .NET mvc application, where I use Bootstrap 5.1 to create a nav-tabs. Each 'a' tag is generated via ActionLink.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="nav-item">
          @Html.ActionLink("Entity", "Details", "Entity", new { id = Model.Id, tab = Entity.TAB_ENTITY }, new { @class = "nav-link"})
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          @Html.ActionLink("Tasks", "Details", "Entity", new { id = Model.Id, tab = Entity.TAB_TASKS }, new { @class = "nav-link active", @aria_current = "page" })
      </li>
</ul>
```

According to Bootstrap documentation, I should use aria-current attribute on 'a' tag to convey active state between tabs. The problem is I can't hardcode that under ActionLink, like I did with nav-link.
I was trying to make a custom HTML helper, but it didn't went well because of the ActionLink.

Currently the effect is like this
[image]
if I hardcode aria-current='Page' and 'nav-link active' in each 'a' tag.

How can I design such a nav-tabs, which will convey active state between tabs? I don't want to use additional js code, since this functionality is already under bootstrap.js

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inside `htmlAttributes`

```
@Html.ActionLink("Entity", "Details", "Entity", new { id = Model.Id, tab = Entity.TAB_ENTITY }, new { @class = "nav-link", @aria_current="page" })
```

**Remember:** Underscore is used as opposed to hyphens within the HTML Attributes

Comment: Html.ActionLink is a Razor method, i.e. it works on the server side, it is not able to respond to what is happening on the browser side on a regular basis. In other words, I can't hardcode that into ActionLink, because then all 'a' tags will have an active state

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink()` reflects `<a aria-current="page" class="nav-link" href="">Entity</a>` in browser

Comment: Correct, but each time a pane is clicked I want to use js code from bootstrap.js to change the active state of a pane (add active class and aria-current to a current nav-link, and remove that class from remaining nav-links)